# How do I recover my USB to a Normal state from a Kali Live Persistance bootable USB?

Tags: kali-linux, bootable-media, format, liveusb, persistence

So, I made a Kali Live Persistance bootable USB but now I want to format and get it to it's normal state. Can someone tell me how to do it? When I try to just right-click format it, It shows the size of the USB as 8 GB even though it's a 32GB USB. Even choosing Restore device defaults doesn't work.

How I made it? I used Rufus. I followed the normal steps with a persistence space of 20GB and That's how I got to this point.

As you can see in the image below, it shows a storage capacity of approximately 8.5 GB even though its a 32 GB pendrive. I set up 20 GB persistence storage using rufus. so I wanted to know is there a way to get that storage back? If yes, How?

[image: Click Here for the image]

P.S. I am currently on windows so a windows tutorial would be recommended. And something that doesn't require me to install softwares will be appreciated.

Comment: Use Disk Management instead and remove all partitions.

Answer (score 1):

Rufus has a mode to restore a bootable USB to generic storage media (because, of course, if an application allows you to change something, it usually also allows you to **revert** those changes).

See that *Boot selection* menu in Rufus? Just select *Non bootable* in there with whatever file system you want, and Rufus will happily restore your USB to a single partition non-bootable regular media, that will use all the available capacity.

Next time, you may also want to look at the Rufus FAQ, which has a [dedicated entry](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#Help_how_do_I_restore_my_USB_to_how_it_was_before_I_created_a_bootable_drive) for this.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't expect rufus to have this feature as well.